# UnicodeDecodeError while pulling in mercurial (hg) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

This error occurred while pulling in Mercurial, couldn't even commit or push for all the actions the same error is occurring. This didn't occur to me in past and I'm using the same Mercurial version 6.1.1

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 6.1.1)
** Extensions loaded: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 61, in <module>
    dispatch.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 144, in run
    status = dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 250, in dispatch
    status = _rundispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 294, in _rundispatch
    ret = _runcatch(req) or 0
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 470, in _runcatch
    return _callcatch(ui, _runcatchfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 480, in _callcatch
    return scmutil.callcatch(ui, func)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/scmutil.py", line 153, in callcatch
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 460, in _runcatchfunc
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1273, in _dispatch
    return runcommand(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 918, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1285, in _runcommand
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 1271, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **strcmdopt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 1887, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 5407, in pull
    other = hg.peer(repo, opts, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 239, in peer
    return _peerorrepo(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 187, in _peerorrepo
    obj = _peerlookup(path).instance(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 645, in instance
    inst = makepeer(ui, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 629, in makepeer
    respurl, info = performhandshake(ui, url, opener, requestbuilder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 568, in performhandshake
    resp = sendrequest(ui, opener, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py", line 288, in sendrequest
    res = opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 557, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1056, in http_error_401
    response = self.http_error_auth_reqed('www-authenticate',
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 524, in http_error_auth_reqed
    return urlreq.httpbasicauthhandler.http_error_auth_reqed(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1005, in http_error_auth_reqed
    return self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 529, in retry_http_basic_auth
    user, pw = self.passwd.find_user_password(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 108, in find_user_password
    self.passwddb.add_password(realm, authuri, user, passwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/ui.py", line 189, in add_password
    _maybestrurl(passwd),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/ui.py", line 166, in _maybestrurl
    return pycompat.rapply(pycompat.strurl, maybebytes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/pycompat.py", line 98, in rapply
    return _rapply(f, xs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/pycompat.py", line 74, in _rapply
    return f(xs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mercurial/pycompat.py", line 293, in strurl
    return url.decode('ascii')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```